# Cant copy because file is too large for format

Tags: hard-drive

I too was getting the error that I could not copy some files as there were over 4 GB.  I was attempting to transfer .avi files.I reformatted the the thumb drive to Mac OS Extended(journaled) however then when I plugged thumb drive in to television set, the TV did not recognise the thumb drive or the files on it.

Is there another format i can use to t enable me to transfer the bigger files and so the television recognises the drive?

Answer (score 2):

Most non-Apple systems usually only are able to handle FAT32.
Many will handle NTFS or EXFAT as well.

FAT32 is limited to a file size of 4GB max per file. HFS+ (what you used) will hold the files, but it won't be recognized. You concluded this correctly.

Try either NTFS or EXFAT. For NTFS formatting you will need a Windows or a current Linux system which can write to NTFS. Another alternative would be to install NTFS drivers with write permissions in your OS X setup, but I'd consider this the least preferred option.

Long story cut short:

1. Try formatting the drive as EXFAT and see if that works
2. Try formatting the drive as NTFS and writing the file within Windows or a modern Linux setup
3. Try splitting the file without re-encoding with special software. You could Google some programs, as I must admit I cannot recommend any right now

3) wouldn't be a true solution but a workaround, so I'll not do a lot of research now, hoping option 1) or 2) do help.